# Configuring Flask-SQLAlchemy to use multiple databases with Flask-Restless

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app that uses Flask-SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to configure it to use multiple databases with the Flask-Restless package.

According to [the docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/), configuring your models to use multiple databases with `__bind_key__` seems pretty straightforward.

However it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I create my app and initialise my database like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://db_user:db_pw@localhost:5432/db_name'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'db1': SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    'db2': 'mysql://db_user:db_pw@localhost:3306/db_name'
}

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLALchemy(app)
```

Then define my models including `__bind_key__`, which should tell SQLAlchemy which DB it needs to use:

```
class PostgresModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'postgres_model_table'
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...


class MySQLModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'mysql_model_table'
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Then I fire up Flask-Restless like this:

```
manager = restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
manager.init_app(app, db)

auth_func = lambda: is_authenticated(app)

manager.create_api(PostgresModel,
                   methods=['GET'],
                   collection_name='postgres_model',
                   authentication_required_for=['GET'],
                   authentication_function=auth_func)

manager.create_api(MySQLModel,
                   methods=['GET'],
                   collection_name='mysql_model',
                   authentication_required_for=['GET'],
                   authentication_function=auth_func)
```

The app runs fine and when I hit `http://localhost:5000/api/postgres_model/[id]` I get the expected JSON response of the object from the Postgres DB (I'm guessing this is because I have it's credentials in SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI).

Although when I hit `http://localhost:5000/api/mysql_model/[id]`, I get a `mysql_model_table` does not exist error, indicating that it's looking in the Postgres DB, not the MySQL one.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was not working because of a simple typo:

```
__bind_key = 'db1'
```

Should have been

```
__bind_key__ = 'db1'
```

I've updated the original question and fixed the typo as an example of how this can work for others.

Comment: How do I access the __bind_key__ of a model to get the database name of that model ?