# remote db initialization in Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have flask app running on Server-A with mysqlDB. Before using the app we did something like this:

```
$ python -c "from your_app import db; db.create_all()"
```

to initialize the DB. Now we are planning to move DB to a new server, Server-B. So the app will be running at Server-A and its mysql DB will be at Server-B.  In this case, how do I need to initialize the database? And where do I need to execute the `create_all()` command? Does Server-B need any Flask specific mysql packages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021292/configuring-flask-sqlalchemy-to-use-multiple-databases-with-flask-restless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have updated the application's database connection information so that `db` now points at the MySQL database on Server B you should be able to use the exact same command on Server A.  Whatever you are using to create the tables should still create the necessary tables in the database on Server B.