# Can we create multiple MySQL Instances in one flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, config

I have two databases say xyz and abc. The thing is I want to have two MySQL instances using one Flask app. 
This is how I initialize one MySQL Instance:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='abcd'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'xyz'
mysql_xyz = MySQL(app)
```

I have another database lets say 'abc'
when I am trying to overwrite 'MYSQL_DB' by:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'abc'
mysql_abc = MySQL(app)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point
>   where response headers were already sent. MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')

However, another alternative is to create a different app altogether under the same script file app.py

```
app1 = Flask(__name__)
app1.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
app1.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
app1.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='abcd'
app1.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'abc'
mysql_abc = MySQL(app1)
```

and this works fine. 
can anyone please let me know how can I overwrite the value of 'MYSQL_DB' config and create another mysql instance using only one app variable.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to create multiple tables within a single database, instead of creating multiple databases.

Else, these will help: 
https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multipledbs.html
[Configuring Flask-SQLAlchemy to use multiple databases with Flask-Restless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021292/configuring-flask-sqlalchemy-to-use-multiple-databases-with-flask-restless)