# How can I initialize more than one SQLAlchemy database

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy

So, Im trying to create two different saved text databases for my website im making out of Flask. Heres the basic rundown of this section:

```
project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
database_file2 = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir, "namedatabase.db"))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file2

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Does anybody know how to add another database file to this? Im trying to use these python commands:

```
$python
>>>from main import db
>>>db.create_all()
>>>exit()
```

to create a "bookdatabase.db", and a "namedatabase.db". Im using repl.it as my environment

Comment: Why do need two databases? Why can't you have multiple tables instead?

Comment: Either way, from a quick and simple Google search I came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15021292/12488201. Hope it helps

Comment: Im a bit new to this actually. How would i go about putting the data into another table instead?

Comment: You are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, right? Whatever you have done to create one table, you can do the same to create another.

Comment: and i actually tried that. But it is a bit difficult to understand knowing how im trying to avoid the bind function

Comment: Sorry, are you stuck understanding the post I shared or with creating multiple tables?

Comment: Yea, im not using actual sql files to do this, im using pythons Flask module. And its a bit difficult to understand things like the bind function, which i think applies to the sql language

Comment: Since you are using `Flask`, you can use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` to make working with `sqlite` really easy. You tagged it in your post, but I can't tell if you are *actually* using it or not. But if you are not, I suggest it to you, and then I suggest looking into this for using binds: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/.

Comment: I don't know much about using multiple databases, so don't take my word as gospel, but if you are new to using databases, I can't imagine you are writing anything too complex. I then doubt you need anything that uses two databases, so you may as well use multiple tables.